# How to inject correct implementation of interface depends on specific bean?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm struggling with creation of architecture that will support various implementation of this interface:

```
    public interface ApiService<T extends BasicDevice> {

    byte[] getDeviceSnap(T basicDevice);
}
```

Generic of this interface should always extend BasicDevice:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BasicDevice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "DEVICE_ID")
    private String deviceId;

    @Column(name = "VEHICLE_ID")
    private int vehicleId;

}
```

The ApiService can have multiple implementation, two for example:

```
@Service
public class ImouService implements ApiService<ImouDevice> {


    @Override
    public byte[] getDeviceSnap(ImouDevice imouDevice) {
        //some implementation
        return new byte[0];
    }
```

And second:

```
@Service
public class DahuaService implements ApiService<DahuaDevice> {

    @Override
    public byte[] getDeviceSnap(DahuaDevice device) {
         //some implementation
        return new byte[0];
    }
}
```

This two implementation have their own generics that are extending from BasicDevice but with their uniq fields, like this:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class DahuaDevice extends BasicDevice {

    @Column(name = "HOST_NAME")
    private String hostname;

}
```

And the problem itself, in code below I retrieving from DB list of beans that extending from BasicDevice, like ImouDevice and DahuaDevice, then I trying to call method for each bean from list, but for that I need injection of apiService with its correct implementation, meaning imouService for ImouDevice, dahuaService for DahuaDevice, etc.But it doesn't know which implementation to use and throws exception - Parameter 2 of constructor in ScheduleTask required a single bean, but 2 were found - dahuaService,imouService

```
public class ScheduleTask {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ScheduleTask.class);
    private final DeviceVehicleRepository deviceVehicleRepository;
    private final UrlDeviceBeanRepository urlDeviceBeanRepository;
    private final ApiService apiService;
    private final S3Service service;
    private final CacheManager cacheManager;

    public ScheduleTask(DeviceVehicleRepository deviceVehicleRepository, UrlDeviceBeanRepository urlDeviceBeanRepository,
                         ApiService apiService, S3Service service, CacheManager cacheManager) {
        this.deviceVehicleRepository = deviceVehicleRepository;
        this.urlDeviceBeanRepository = urlDeviceBeanRepository;
        this.apiService = apiService;
        this.service = service;
        this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * ?")//every minute
    public void getSnaps() {
        Long timestamp = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
        log.info("Started scheduled task to get snapshots");
        List<BasicDevice> allVehiclesWithDevices = (List<BasicDevice>) deviceVehicleRepository.findAll();
        allVehiclesWithDevices.parallelStream().forEach(basicDevice ->
        {
            byte[] contentBytes = apiService.getDeviceSnap(basicDevice);//here it doesn't which implementation to use
            if (contentBytes.length > 0) {
                urlDeviceBeanRepository.save(new UrlDeviceBean(contentBytes,
                        basicDevice.getVehicleId(), timestamp));
            }
        });
    }
```

How to always inject correct implementation depends on bean type?

Comment: can you try with @Qualifier annotation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run all the services, then you need to inject collection of services, try something like this

```
Collection<ApiService<?>> apiServices;
```

and then loop through the collection of apiService method for each apiService in the collection to get your snaps